# m-point-homogeneous, but not (m+1)-point-homogeneous

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

It is straightforward to check that the discrete cube $Q=\{0,1\}^n$ with $\ell^1$-metric is 3-point-homogeneous, but not 4-point-homogeneous (assuming $n$ is large).
In other words, if $A\subset Q$ has at most 3 points, then any distance-preserving map $A\to Q$ can be extended to an isometry $Q\to Q$, but there is a 4-point set for which it does not hold.

I would like to see an example of $m$-point-homogeneous that is not $(m+1)$-point-homogeneous for $m\geqslant 4$.

Comment: Do you mean finite metric spaces?

Comment: @WlodAA if you have an infinite one, then show it to me :)

Comment: (Everywhere I refer to a polytope in what follows I mean its vertices regarded as a metric space with the $\ell^2$ norm.) Some googling found a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.13096) showing that the $n$-orthoplex is $2n$-point homogeneous (Corollary 4). It also contains the example that both the regular $n$-gon and the $n$-simplex are $n$-point homogeneous but they are not "not $n+1$-point homogeneous" in your sense since they don't have $n+1$ points at all. I can't find any examples in the paper which are $2k-1$-point homogeneous but not $2k$-point homogeneous for $k \ge 3$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan for a space with $<n$ points, the $n$-point homogeneity rather sounds like an empty condition, hence true (however to make things reasonable one should allow non-injective families, or equivalently require, in the definition of $n$-homogeneity, $n'$-homogeneity for all $n'<n$). So, a finite set with all points at distance $1$ should be $n$-homogeneous for all $n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan right, for me all of them are all-set-homogeneous.

Answer (score 3):

The [Schläfli graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_graph), viewed as a metric space, is 4-homogeneous but not 5-homogeneous.